# Слово "капці" - літературне чи діалектизм?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники, діалектизми

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kapci) подають без жодної позначки, отже, виходить, воно літературне:

> **КА́ПЦІ**, ів, мн. (одн. капець, пця, чол.). Легкі туфлі, переважно для хати. Його одіж — то латка на латці.. На ногах із онуч старих капці (Іван Франко, XIII, 1954, 134).

Однак [тут](https://www.slideshare.net/tan4ikbah/2-76608963) його подають серед діалектизмів Вінниччини:

> **Взуття** - **капці**.

Отож слово **"капці" - літературне чи діалектизм**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Найповнішому тлумачному словнику української мови](https://eslovnyk.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96)  знаходимо це слово без позначки діал.:

> **Капці**
>
> -ів, мн. (одн. ка́пець, -пця, ч.).
> Легкі туфлі, перев. для хати. || Вид легкого взуття на Сході.

У [Словнику за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/22132-kapec.html#show_point)  знаходимо:

> **Капці=капець**  -пця, м. 1) Кожаная обувь безъ голенищъ, опорки, туфли. Від злого давця бери й капця. Ном. А дід бабці купив капці, та короткі були, то втяв пальці. О. 1861. XI. 68. (Н. п.). 2) Родъ суконныхъ шитыхъ носковъ. Гол. Од. 67. Иногда къ нимъ пришивается продолженіе, охватывающее икры ногъ. Шух. І. 125. 3) Переносно: конецъ, смерть. Як де нагрюкають якого жида, там йому й капець. Екатер. у. Слов. Д. Эварн. Cм. капут.

У [Блозі професора Пономарева](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2009/12/post-4.html) знаходимо:

> Замість *„тапочки"* краще казати **„капці"**. Це легке хатнє взуття. Так що тут в нас є кращий синонім.

Отже, словники вказують, що це нормативне слово, запозичене з [польської](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm).